# save binary file to local dir - salesforce attacments

Tags: php, salesforce, binaryfiles

I have a function in salesforce in which i get an attachment that could be any file type (pdf,xls,png,...).

```
function getData($access_token,$instance_url,$url){
    $url = $instance_url."/services/data/v32.0/".$url;
    $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth ' . $access_token);
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    //curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    //curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $requestBody = curl_exec ($ch);
    $result = json_decode($requestBody, true);
    return $result;

}
$attId = "00P0f00000ly5ZCEAY";
$body = "sobjects/Attachment/00P0f00000ly5ZCEAY/Body";

$file = getData($access_token,$instance_url,$body);
```

the result of this is file is returned in binary form.

so $file = //Some Binary File

what can i do with $file to save it locally?

right now the result of this function is:

```
??%???T?)???)?eFa???Bɶ?l6???,?0?l?%kc?w?cՂX8?"?*Q>?ē??/y???=??T??Ċ?sǓ???l...
.
...
```

it appears to be trying to print the file to my screen.

Comment: you might want to add a tag called `Salesforce` as the getData function is not PHP native.

Comment: its a custom function. that part is only relevant to describe the variable $file, which is a binary file.  i will add the tag though.

Comment: You mentioned that it echos to the screen, that tells me it's coming from the `getData` function

Comment: ah, i see what you are saying, then yes, you are correct.  ill make some edits.

Answer (score 0):

needed to set correct curl_opts

```
        $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth ' . $access_token);
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```